# Gravel beds near foundation

Tags: foundation

My wife and I bought a new house a week back in Merrimack, NH.

How soon should we put the gravel beds near the foundation?
Should we put it before the winter and snow or can we wait and put it in the Spring of next year?

Comment: This _desperately_ needs more information! _Why_ are you installing gravel beds? What are you hoping to accomplish with them? Please [edit] your question to include this vital info, or we won't be able to answer it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can explain why you see gravel beds around houses in your neighborhood, as I live in New Hampshire less than 30 minutes away from the town of Merrimack.

Most houses in this region do not have rain gutters. (I was surprised by this when I moved here because where I came from, nearly every house had rain gutters.) I think the reason for the lack of gutters is related to the heavy, wet snow that we get here, the buildup of ice dams and the damage to gutters in the winter if you don't use a gutter melting system. I know someone who takes his gutters down before winter so they don't get ripped down by ice. Weird, but true.

So rain water falls in a drip line near the foundation on any side of the house that has a sloped roof section above it and no rain gutters.

If the soil around the house is fertile loam or is high in clay, dripping water forms a mud puddle near the foundation, and falling rain splashes mud onto the house and makes a mess. In that case, a strip of gravel near the foundation will prevent the formation of mud and will keep the house clean.

If the soil is sandy / gravely glacial deposits, as it is in most of this region, dripping water from the roof washes away the finest particles from the soil and leaves a nice strip of gravel next to the house with no effort by the home owner. It *looks* like a gravel bed, but it is formed naturally by dripping water. Since there is no mud, any splashes on the house from the natural gravel strip are clean water, and the house stays clean. No additional gravel is needed in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply MTA.

Answer (score 1):

...you can wait 100 years. "Gravel beds near the foundation" are a landscaping choice, not a thing any house "needs" at all.

Comment: I think it's a question of what problem are you trying to solve?   If Ecnerwal got it right, it's an astetic issue.   If you are trying to solve a problem, like drainage or??? that makes a difference, please clarify your question so we can better help you.